# Sql query based on R values in datatable

Tags: sql, r, rmysql

I have few blank values in one of my columns in dataset. I need to make sql query to database with only this few id (86) that contain missing value.

I have in mind something like that (not just paste id to in statement):

```
SELECT x.id,
x.sent 
FROM x
WHERE x.id IN [my R vector with id]
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Igniste, I _think_ I interpreted your question completely in my answer. If I missed it, however, you will need to add a lot more context to your question, making it as reproducible as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glue_sql` will expand vectors into a comma separated list if you use `*` after the variable name in the `glue` expression.

```
glue::glue_sql("
  SELECT x.id,
  x.sent 
  FROM x
  WHERE x.id IN ({idVector*})
", .con = con)
```

`con` is a DBI connection to your database

Answer (score 0):

*Conjecture.*

Real data is in `#sourcemt` (a temp table, the "#" is purely local for my database, ignore it).

```r
sourcemt <- mt <- transform(mtcars, id = seq_len(nrow(mtcars)))
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "#sourcemt", sourcemt)

mt <- head(mt)
mt$cyl[c(1,3,4)] <- NA
mt
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb id
# Mazda RX4         21.0  NA  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  2
# Datsun 710        22.8  NA  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  3
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  NA  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  4
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  5
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  6
```

We want to fix the missing `cyl` values.

```r
miss_ids <- mt$id[is.na(mt$cyl)]
miss_ids
# [1] 1 3 4
(qmarks <- paste(rep("?", length(miss_ids)), collapse = ","))
# [1] "?,?,?"
fixmt <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("select id, cyl from #sourcemt where id in (%s)", qmarks), params = miss_ids)
fixmt
#   id cyl
# 1  1   6
# 2  3   4
# 3  4   6
```

(FYI, the `qmarks` parts are using parameter-binding for safe querying of data without `paste`-ing or `sprintf`-ing the data into the query. See [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) for good discussions about this.)

From here, we just need to merge them and coalesce the missing values back in. (Both methods below should capture the output back into `mt`.)

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mt %>%
  left_join(fixmt, by = "id", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  mutate(cyl = coalesce(cyl, cyl.y)) %>%
  select(-cyl.y)
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb id
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  2
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  3
# 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  4
# 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  5
# 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  6
```

## base R

```r
merge(mt, fixmt, by = "id", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".y")) |>
  transform(cyl = ifelse(is.na(cyl), cyl.y, cyl), cyl.y = NULL)
#   id  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3  3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4  4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5  5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6  6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```